# SharePoint Configuration Wizard fails Step 8

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

The Sharepoint Server 2013 Configuration Wizard fails for me in Step 8 and returns the following error:

> "Failed to create sample data. An Exception of type System.NullReferenceException was thrown. Additional exception information:Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

My current situation:

- Not an upgrade. Clean installation.
- Dev environment (no internet)
- Server2012 318GB Free space
- Sharepoint Server 2013 Product Version: 15.0.4571.1502
- SQL 2008

I have tried:

•
Looking for the `Analytic_ folder` to share (there is no such folder). I even searched the entire `C:` for `*Analytics`. I searched the registry as well for Analytics

•
Ran Wizard as Admin

•
Made sure AppFabric Caching Service SQL Server Agent for SharePoint database were running and then ran `psconfig.exe -cmd Configdb Create SkipRegisterAsDistributedCacheHost` in powershell and the error states that psconfig.exe is not recognized

•
Checked for latest updates (even though I am in a dev environment)

Please assist.

Answer (score -1):

I can point to the right post/solution on the below:

[Solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/installing-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-2012-standalone-installation)